# Change layout of dockable windows in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, docking

Is it possible to change the layout of dockable windows in Notepad++? When I organize tool windows (like FTP explorer or FTP log window) they stick to the edges this way only:

[image]

I'd like them to be shown this way:

[image]

Is it this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++'s docking is quite primitive compared to, say, Visual Studio or MATLAB's.

It's not possible for real dockable windows, but you can partially simulate it by tearing the windows off (drag their title bar until an outline of the window appears) and arranging the floating windows.

To avoid accidental loss if the windows are moved, you can back up the config.xml file.